# Proper idiom for std::string assignment

Tags: c++, string

When constructing a `std::string` from a `const char*`, I often use the following pattern:

```
const char* p = GetString();
std::string s(p);
```

I suppose I could use the similar pattern:

```
const char* p = GetString();
std::string s = p;
```

But, when I want to assign, rather than construct, to a `std::string` from a `const char*`, I have too many choices:

```
s = p;
s.assign(p);
std::string(p).swap(s);
```

Are the choices above more-or-less equivalent? Which should I prefer, and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go for readability, and just use the idiomatic `operator=` for assignment. Also, directly construct the `std::string` from the `const char*`.

```
std::string s(GetString());
s = GetString();
```

Comment: Prefer s=GetString(); as that has no chance of giving you an accidental function (Most Vexing Parse - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you'd just do

`std::string s = GetString();`.

For assignment, do

`s = GetString();`.

This means that the `std::string` object has the maximum information available to it to produce the fastest operation.

Answer (score 2):

The operator= and .assign are pretty much identical, you should prefer the operator= form as it's more readable.

The last isn't the same. Swapping the content does reduce the amount of time spent on constructing a given object as it doesn't make a copy, it only moves content around. Your syntax first copies p into an std::string and then swaps it with s, which isn't any more performant than the rest as you're still duplicating p. If P had been an std::string somewhere else that you were destructing anyway, this would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are basically the same thing; `assign` has a few more overloads that allow you to do interesting things.  I would choose the straightforward `=`, because it's clearer.

The last one seems very verbose and non-intuitive; I'm not sure why you'd do that (unless you were desperate to reclaim the memory that `s` is using).